# C++ Call a class method in a separate thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

Say, I have a class with two methods: a main thread and a separate one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
    bool is_ready;
public:
    Foo()
    {
        is_ready = false;
    }

    void async_func()
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(2000));  // do some long stuff
        is_ready = true;
    }

    void main_thread_func()
    {
        thread t([&] (Foo* foo) { foo->async_func(); }, this);
        t.join();
        
        while(true)
        {
            cout << is_ready << endl;
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.main_thread_func();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to see a message with the "is_ready" state to learn the progress of another thread's function. Actually, I can see messages only when it make "true".

How to see all the progress not waiting when the function stops?

Comment: maybe it is just in the example, but spawning a thread and immediately joining it is rather pointless. There is no concurrency in your example

Comment: Try moving `t.join();` to immediately *after* the `while(true)` loop.

Comment: @G.M. It works now, thanks!

Comment: once you fixed that you need to add some synchronization for `is_ready`, make it a `std::atomic` or use a `mutex` to avoid data race

Comment: Do you know what `t.join()` does?

Answer (score 0):

You call the join function before while so main thread is waiting to finished the created thread. You should call join function in right place for example after while(true).